# Set a token as the default value of a new field

Tags: 7, entities, tokens

In Drupal 7, you can set defaults values for most fields. Is it possible to set a token as the default value.

I remember this being possible in Drupal 6, but it doesn't seem possible in Drupal 7.

There is a thread [here](http://drupal.org/node/691078) that discuss the possibility, but its not clear if it was solved.

Comment: There is an open feature request for this in module Token (http://drupal.org/node/1070878)

Comment: A possible solution workaround is here: http://drupal.org/node/1070878#comment-5103914

Comment: Here is a related Drupal 8 core patch for this (http://drupal.org/node/1308564).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information do you try to get??

In one of my Content Type, I need to retrieve the node ID. I found that the token for the current node ID is this:

```
[current-page:url:args:last]
```

Tested and working for me!!

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MODULE_hook_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Prevent replace tokens on field admin ui form.
  if (!is_null($element['#entity'])) {
    // Determine the $user. If entity has uid, try to load. If can't, use the
    // global $user.
    if (isset($element['#entity']->uid)) {
      if (!$user = user_load($element['#entity']->uid)) {
        global $user;
      }
    }

    // Build data for token replacement.
    $data = array(
      $element['#entity_type'] => $element['#entity'],
      'user' => $user,
    );
    // Eg. the body field, the default value is stored in
    // $element['#default_value']
    if (isset($element['#default_value']) && !is_array($element['#default_value'])) {
      $element['#default_value'] = token_replace($element['#default_value'], $data);
    }
    // Eg. the link field, the default value is stored in
    // $element['#default_value']['url']
    else if (is_array($element['#default_value'])) {
      foreach ($element['#default_value'] as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
          $element['#default_value'][$key] = token_replace($value, $data);
        }
      }
    }
    // Eg. the text field, the default value is stored in
    // $element['value']['#default_value']
    else if (isset($element['value'])) {
      if (isset($element['value']['#default_value']) && !is_array($element['value']['#default_value'])) {
        $element['value']['#default_value'] = token_replace($element['value']['#default_value'], $data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Install the [Field default token](https://drupal.org/project/field_default_token) module.

> This module enables to use tokens as field default values.
>   The main discussion: [#1070878: Allow tokens to be used in the default value of a field](https://drupal.org/node/1070878).

Comment: The module doesn't appear to have good support, and there are a number of open issues.